# MySQL: User online status [HELP]

Tags: mysql, sql

I already make a user online status for friends only

```
SELECT * FROM users 
WHERE
    (id_user IN 
        (SELECT CASE 
            WHEN friend_one = '{$id}' 
                THEN friend_two 
            WHEN friend_two = '{$id}' 
                THEN friend_one 
            END 
        FROM friends 
        WHERE status = '1')
    ) AND (status = '1' OR ($date - last_login) <= 300)
```

And it works, this mysql only show the list of friends login status.

But the problem is when i try to make the another user login status, that only shows the list of another people that logged in but not in our friend list.

```
SELECT * FROM users 
WHERE
    (id_user NOT IN 
        (SELECT CASE 
            WHEN friend_one = '{$id}' 
                THEN friend_two 
            WHEN friend_two = '{$id}' 
                THEN friend_one 
            END 
        FROM friends 
        WHERE status = '1')
    ) AND (status = '1' OR ($date - last_login) <= 300)
```

So this is the result i want

```
Logged as: khrisna
Friend list: Ben, Alpha, Ralph
All User: Ben, Alpha, John, Mark, Zayn

Online friend list: Ben, Alpha

Another online user: John, Mark, Zayn
```

Can somebody help me to reach the result i want?

---

**UPDATE**

`users` table

[image]

`friends` table

[image]

---

I want to make something like this for the result

> Online user : Khrisna Gunanasurya // logined account
>
> Friend list online : Alpha, John // online friends of logined account
>
> Other user online: Mark, Ralph // other user that login and not friend of logined account

Comment: Please provide table schema, sample data and desired result in a tabular form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it:

Get all friends that are online

```
SELECT *
  FROM
(
  SELECT CASE WHEN friend_one = ? THEN friend_two ELSE friend_one END friend
    FROM friends
   WHERE ? IN(friend_one, friend_two)
     AND status = 1
) f JOIN users u
    ON f.friend = u.id_user
 WHERE status = 1 OR last_login >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 300;
```

Get all non friends that are online

```sql
SELECT *
  FROM users u 
 WHERE id_user <> ?
   AND NOT EXISTS
(
  SELECT *
    FROM friends
   WHERE ? IN(friend_one, friend_two)
     AND status = 1
     AND u.id_user = CASE WHEN friend_one = ? THEN friend_two ELSE friend_one END
)
   AND (status = 1 OR last_login >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 300);
```

*Question mark represents a value of an Id of logged in user (e.g. Khrisna Gunanasurya)*

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ec4c7a/8)** demo

---

Your php code might look like

```
$sql = "SELECT *
  FROM
(
  SELECT CASE WHEN friend_one = ? THEN friend_two ELSE friend_one END friend
    FROM friends
   WHERE ? IN(friend_one, friend_two)
     AND status = 1
) f JOIN users u
    ON f.friend = u.id_user
 WHERE status = 1 OR last_login >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 300";

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array_fill(0, 2, $id));
```

Comment: then what will be the value ie the question mark given ??..you havnt supplied any value there

Comment: Why i got this warning ? 
`Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: no parameters were bound`

Comment: *Why i got this warning ?*. That's because you need to bind a value of an id of a logged in user before you execute your query. Don't use query string interpolation like you did `...friend_one = '{$id}'...`.

Comment: @AvinashBabu Read and see examples here [PDOStatement::execute](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) and here [PDOStatement::bindParam](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php)